# Why Couldn't the Nuke that Blew Up Cloud 9 Be Traced?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

This could be my memory and I could have missed something, but I know Balter requested a nuclear warhead from Adama to use for the Cylon detector (which worked, but which he claimed didn't work).  It's never clear that he used the entire warhead and I always thought it was this warhead that he gave to Gina Invire.

Don't they keep track fo all the warheads on the *Galactica* and the *Pegasus*?  Wouldn't they be able to show that the only missing nuclear warhead was the one Baltar had and trace it back to him and prove he was connected to the explosion?

Or did the warhead come from somewhere else?  And, if so, where did it come from?

Comment: I believe (but can't verify at this time) that, when the ship blew up, Baltar was president, and essentially called off the investigation into where the nuke came from. Otherwise, yes, it would've been traced back to him.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I know it went off on his inauguration day, but I would think that both Adamas would still pursue it if they thought they could make it public.

Comment: "It's never clear that he used the entire warhead..." - it's a while since I saw that episode but as I recall it wasn't clear that he needed the warhead at all.  He only asked for it because Head Six told him to.  I don't think he actually needed it for the detector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Battlestar Galactica wiki page on Gaius Baltar](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Gaius_Baltar):

> In an attempt to cover up his role in giving Gina the nuclear warhead
>   used to detonate Cloud 9, Baltar orders Adama to stop any further
>   investigation into the destruction of Cloud 9 and two other ships (he
>   correctly guesses that the conflagration was started by Gina Inviere).

Comment: You'd think Adama would have continued investigating in secret in that situation.

Comment: Blame the writers ;/ At least it's better than their great idea at the very end ;/